# FIXED jQuery Validate + php check user exits

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to add to a form, which is validated with jQuery validate, and a PHP script where I check if the user (`usuario`) exits. Each user has a different folder. To check if the user exits, I check if the folder exists then if exists, tell there is an error and I don't want to stop the form from being submitted. If not, I create the sub-folder with the username and create the folder.

Currently, I use the AJAX solution, but the PHP is not executed, and it won't print any echo on it.
I have been reading more about AJAX and about the remote attribute in jQuery validate but neither way I can get my functionality to work out.

**With Ajax** (or what I have understood as ajax)

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
              var username = $(this).val();
              $.post('check_user.php', {'usuario':username}, function(data) { 
                  $("#user-result").html(data); 
                  form.submit();
              });
 }
```

**With remote**

```
"usuario":{
         required: true,
         rangelength: [3, 10],
         remote: {
                url: "check-user.php",
                type: "get",
                data:{
                    usuarios: function(){
                       return $('#usuario').val();
                    }
                }
         }
}
```

**My PHP**

```
<?php
    $user = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
    $dir = "usuarios/$user";
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        if(!mkdir($dir, 0777, true)) {
            echo 'Fallo al crear las carpetas...'
        }   
        $doc = new_xmldoc('1.0');
        $root = $doc->add_root('historial');
        $fp = @fopen('historial.xml','w');
        if(!$fp) {
            echo 'Fallo al crear historial.xml'
        }
        fwrite($fp,$doc->dumpmem());
        fclose($fp);
        echo 'true';
    }
 ?>
```

**Piece of my form (HTML)**

```
<form id="register" action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <div class="elRegister"><label>Usuario:</label>
    <input name="usuario" id="usuario" type="text" size="16"></div>
```

UPDATE:
Closing correctly the brackets i continue having problems.The rules goes fine but after filling correctly my form, when i press submit button it makes nothing. If something in my form is wrong it will display the error corrrectly.
My script will have the following structure:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($, W, D) {
        var validaForm = {};
        validaForm.UTIL =
                {
                    setupFormValidation: function()
                    {
                        //Reglas de validacion
                        $("#register").validate({
                            debug:true,
                            rules: {
                            },
                            messages: {
                            },
                            submitHandler: function(form) {
                                var username = $(this).val();
                                $.post('check_user.php', {'usuario':username}, function(data) {
                                    $("#user-result").html(data);
                                    form.submit();
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }            
                }
        $(D).ready(function($) {
            validaForm.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
        });

    })(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

Thanks for everything and if you need more things of my code, simply ask.

FIXED
Finally i hve been able to fix this problem. I found the solution in here: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qf6o3MIcAtA)
The solution was to use both, ajax and remote rule. With remote rule i check if the user exists and with the ajax i override the form submit and write another one instead which look like:

```
$("#register").submit(function() {
        var valido = $("#register").valid(); 

        if(valido){
            var $inputs = $('#register :input');

            // not sure if you wanted this, but I thought I'd add it.
            // get an associative array of just the values.
            var values = {};
            $inputs.each(function() {
                values[this.name] = $(this).val();
            });
            alert("Formulario valido");

            $.get("crear_usuario.php",values);
        }  
        else{
            alert("Formulario no valido");
        }
    });
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Your submit handler is not closed. You are missing a `);}` after your closing-brace for your callback.

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly closing submitHandler. Here is the fixed code.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    var username = $(this).val();
    $.post('check_user.php', {'usuario':username}, function(data) { 
        $("#user-result").html(data); 
        form.submit();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bijan fixed. Still not working but now a step ahead. I have updated the code so it gives more perspective